# CreateProcessWithLogonW, to create process as another user on different desktop, fails with browser

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

*First of all it's hard to find a sophisticated title, because the whole situation is complicated and confusing.*

I'm trying to create a Process as a user with restricted rights (user is part of the "Users"-group). The process should spawn on another desktop(let's name it "test"), not on the `"default"`-desktop. The process which uses the `CreateProcessWithLogonW` function is running with admin rights. While a normal application (notepad, vlc, winrar) runs without a problem, browser applications like IE, Firefox, Chrome seem to have a problem. The were started but they're instantly closing without an errorcode. If I'm using a user with administration rights every application runs without an error.

I'm adding ACEs to the winstation and desktop's DACL. Also if I start `cmd.exe` like this and try to run `firefox`the same problem occurs. I'm using python 2.7 with ctypes and win32api:

```
from _ctypes import Array, POINTER, sizeof, byref
from ctypes import wintypes, windll, WinError
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import BYTE, HANDLE, DWORD, BOOL, LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, LPVOID

from win32con import CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, READ_CONTROL, WRITE_DAC, \
GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION, DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS, DESKTOP_READOBJECTS
import win32con
from win32security import ACL_REVISION_DS
import win32security
import win32service


WINSTA_ALL = (win32con.WINSTA_ACCESSCLIPBOARD  | win32con.WINSTA_ACCESSGLOBALATOMS | \
win32con.WINSTA_CREATEDESKTOP    | win32con.WINSTA_ENUMDESKTOPS      |\
win32con.WINSTA_ENUMERATE        | win32con.WINSTA_EXITWINDOWS       |\
win32con.WINSTA_READATTRIBUTES   | win32con.WINSTA_READSCREEN        |\
win32con.WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES  | win32con.DELETE                   |\
win32con.READ_CONTROL            | win32con.WRITE_DAC                |\
win32con.WRITE_OWNER)

DESKTOP_ALL = (win32con.DESKTOP_CREATEMENU      | win32con.DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW  |\
win32con.DESKTOP_ENUMERATE       | win32con.DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL   |\
win32con.DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK | win32con.DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD |\
win32con.DESKTOP_READOBJECTS     | win32con.DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP |\
win32con.DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS    | win32con.DELETE                |\
win32con.READ_CONTROL            | win32con.WRITE_DAC             |\
win32con.WRITE_OWNER)


GENERIC_ACCESS =  (win32con.GENERIC_READ    | win32con.GENERIC_WRITE |\
win32con.GENERIC_EXECUTE | win32con.GENERIC_ALL)



INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400

CData = Array.__base__
LPBYTE = POINTER(BYTE)

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('hProcess',    HANDLE),
        ('hThread',     HANDLE),
        ('dwProcessId', DWORD),
        ('dwThreadId',  DWORD),
    ]
LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)


class STARTUPINFOW(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('cb',              wintypes.DWORD),
                ('lpReserved',      wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpDesktop',       wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('lpTitle',         wintypes.LPWSTR),
                ('dwX',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwY',             wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYSize',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwXCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwYCountChars',   wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFillAttribute', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('dwFlags',         wintypes.DWORD),
                ('wShowWindow',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('cbReserved2',     wintypes.WORD),
                ('lpReserved2',     LPBYTE),
                ('hStdInput',       wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdOutput',      wintypes.HANDLE),
                ('hStdError',       wintypes.HANDLE))

LPSTARTUPINFOW = POINTER(STARTUPINFOW)


windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW.restype = BOOL
windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW.argtypes = [
    LPCWSTR, # lpUsername
    LPCWSTR, # lpDomain
    LPCWSTR, # lpPassword
    DWORD,   # dwLogonFlags
    LPCWSTR, # lpApplicationName
    LPWSTR,  # lpCommandLine (inout)
    DWORD,   # dwCreationFlags
    LPVOID, # lpEnvironment  (force Unicode)
    LPCWSTR, # lpCurrentDirectory
    LPSTARTUPINFOW, # lpStartupInfo
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION, # lpProcessInfo (out)
]

def CreateProcessWithLogonW(
    lpUsername=None, 
    lpDomain=None, 
    lpPassword=None, 
    dwLogonFlags=0, 
    lpApplicationName=0, 
    lpCommandLine=None,
    dwCreationFlags=0, 
    lpEnvironment=None, 
    lpCurrentDirectory=None,
    startupInfo=None):

    if (lpCommandLine is not None and not isinstance(lpCommandLine, CData)):
        lpCommandLine = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(lpCommandLine)

    dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT     

    if startupInfo is None:
        startupInfo = STARTUPINFOW(sizeof(STARTUPINFOW))

    processInformation = PROCESS_INFORMATION(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

    success = windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW(
        lpUsername, lpDomain, lpPassword, dwLogonFlags, lpApplicationName,
        lpCommandLine, dwCreationFlags, lpEnvironment, lpCurrentDirectory, 
        byref(startupInfo), byref(processInformation))

    if not success:
        raise WinError()
    return processInformation


if __name__ == '__main__':

    user_group_sid = win32security.LookupAccountName('','Users')[0]

    #
    #Adding rights for user group "users" to winsta0
    #
    #getting winsta0 handle
    hwinsta = win32service.OpenWindowStation("winsta0",False,READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC )
    #getting security descriptor by winsta0-handle
    sec_desc_winsta = win32security.GetUserObjectSecurity(hwinsta,win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION |win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    #getting DACL from security descriptor
    dacl_winsta = sec_desc_winsta.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    if dacl_winsta is None:
        #create DACL if not exisiting
        dacl_winsta=win32security.ACL()
    #Adding ACEs to DACL for specific user group
    dacl_winsta.AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL_REVISION_DS,GENERIC_ACCESS,user_group_sid)
    dacl_winsta.AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL_REVISION_DS,WINSTA_ALL,user_group_sid)
    #setting modified DACL for winsta0
    win32security.SetSecurityInfo(hwinsta, win32security.SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,None,None,dacl_winsta,None)

    #
    #Adding rights for user group "users" to desktop
    #
    #getting handle of different Desktop
    hdesk = win32service.OpenDesktop("test",0 ,False,READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC |DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS | DESKTOP_READOBJECTS)
    #getting security descriptor by desktop-handle
    sec_desc_desk = win32security.GetUserObjectSecurity(hdesk,win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION |win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION )
    #getting DACL from security descriptor
    dacl_desk = sec_desc_desk.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
    if dacl_desk is None:
        #create DACL if not exisiting
        dacl_desk=win32security.ACL()
    #Adding ACEs to DACL for specific user group
    dacl_desk.AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL_REVISION_DS,GENERIC_ACCESS,user_group_sid)
    dacl_desk.AddAccessAllowedAce(ACL_REVISION_DS,DESKTOP_ALL,user_group_sid)
    #setting modified DACL for desktop
    win32security.SetSecurityInfo(hdesk, win32security.SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,None,None,dacl_desk,None)

    firefox = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
    notepad = "C:\\windows\\notepad.exe"

    si = STARTUPINFOW()
    si.lpDesktop = "winsta0\\test"

    pi = CreateProcessWithLogonW("test", 
                                ".", 
                                "password",
                                0x00000001,
                                None,
                                firefox,
                                CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                                startupInfo=si)
```

The weird thing is, if I'm switching to the "test"-desktop and using `ShellRunas` (shift+right-click -> run as different user) it works perfectly. So it seems like I'm missing to grant my user some rights, but I don't know which rights.

So here are my questions:

1. Do I use `CreateProccesWithLogonW` correctly for my purpose?
2. What's the difference between `CreateProccesWithLogonW` and `Shellrunas`?
3. How does `Shellrunas` works behind the scene?

Comment: A window station is a container for desktop objects. For the `GENERIC_ACCESS` ACE, the existing `WinSta0` entries set the inheritance flags `CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE | INHERIT_ONLY_ACE`, and they use `NO_PROPAGATE_INHERIT_ACE` for the `WINSTA_ALL` entry. Use [`AddAccessAllowedAceEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374951) to control the inhertance flags.

Comment: I've already tried this and tried all possible flag combination, unfortunately this doesn't solved my problem.

Comment: `winsta0` is `winsta0\default`  if any one administrative user install app for every user , can access and control it.  why try to hard ? is a microsoft windows os, scan openning  all windows and do what you want(ofcourse administrator level).